# unable application to launch appium python

Tags: appium, appium-android, python-appium

`$ adb shell`
`$ dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus'`

packages & activity is -- `mCurrentFocus=Window{120f4c3 u0 in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping/com.amazon.mShop.sso.SigninPromptActivity}`

Package -- in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping
avtivity -- com.amazon.mShop.sso.SigninPromptActivity

and my code is--

`import unittest
 from appium import webdriver
 import time
class TestClass(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        desired_caps = {}
        desired_caps['platformName'] = 'Android'
        desired_caps['appiumVersion'] = '1.9.0'
        desired_caps['platformVersion'] = '6.0.1'
        desired_caps['deviceName'] = 'Moto G3'
        desired_caps['browserName'] = ''
        desired_caps['name'] = 'Sample rough'
        desired_caps['appPackage'] = 'in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping'
        desired_caps['appActivity'] = 'com.amazon.mShop.sso.SigninPromptActivity'
        self.driver = webdriver.Remote('http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub', desired_caps)`

`def test_open_App(self):
        print "=======================  START   ==============================="
        print "rough Name : Hello Tester"`

`def tearDown(self):
        time.sleep(2)
        self.driver.quit()
        print "=======================   END   ==============================="`
`if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()`

guys can you help me how to launch app, I am trying with same method with other application like **calculator** , it's working perfectly but some application is not working,

check the error code -- Link [error response](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1Yj2sr1mFwY9mNPe-SqQOTabsRcPsDnTk5VFljoeT0y0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

after doing some research I found some points to launch any application, first of all, you have to find all the activity of your application what you wanted to launch through appium testing,
Step 1: `adb shell pm dump PACKAGE_NAME | grep -A 1 <Package Name>`
Step 2: Try with manual launch application through the terminal by using this commend

`adb shell am start -S -n <Package>/<Activity>`

If you are able to launch, then give the same **Package and Activity** , I am recommending to do activity one by one, **package** will not change only activity will change, starting activity is very important to launch the application,

you will find like this types of details from terminal/command prompt
`........`
`................`
`time="9/10/2018, 12:07 PM" type=MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND package=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping class=com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity 
        time="9/10/2018, 12:07 PM" type=MOVE_TO_BACKGROUND package=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping class=com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity 
        time="9/10/2018, 12:07 PM" type=MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND package=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping class=com.amazon.mShop.home.web.MShopWebGatewayActivity 
        time="9/10/2018, 12:07 PM" type=MOVE_TO_BACKGROUND package=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping class=com.amazon.mShop.home.web.MShopWebGatewayActivity 
        time="9/10/2018, 12:07 PM" type=MOVE_TO_FOREGROUND package=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping class=com.amazon.mShop.sso.SigninPromptActivity 
        time="9/10/2018, 12:07 PM" type=MOVE_TO_BACKGROUND package=in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping class=com.amazon.mShop.sso.SigninPromptActivity`
`........`
`................`

**here only one activity is important to launch through appium that is `class=com.amazon.mShop.home.HomeActivity`

---------I hope it will resolve issues to launch application through appium